# How to update content of glightbox slider?

Tags: javascript, ajax, lightbox

I'm using Glightbox to create gallery with images description.
I would like to update text of button on click.
When button is clicked and lightbox is reopened text on button is changed.
How to change text on button without reopening a lightbox?

Glightbox documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/biati-digital/glightbox)

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>

            <head>
                <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet" />
                <link
                    rel="stylesheet"
                    href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
                    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
                    crossorigin="anonymous"
                />
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="demo/css/style.css" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/glightbox.css" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
            </head>

            <body>

                <!-- Images with description example -->
                <section class="section pair">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <ul class="box-container three-cols">
                                    <li class="box">
                                        <div class="inner">
                                            <a href="demo/img/large/gm8.jpg" class="glightbox2" data-glightbox="title: Description Right; description: .custom-desc1; descPosition: left;">
                                                <img src="demo/img/small/gm8.jpg" alt="image" />
                                            </a>

                                            <div class="glightbox-desc custom-desc1">
                                                <p>
                                                    <button id="button1" onclick="choose_button(this.id)">Wybierz1</button></p>
                                               
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            
                <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/animejs@3.1.0/lib/anime.min.js"></script>
                <script src="demo/js/valde.min.js"></script>
                <script src="dist/js/glightbox.js"></script>
                <script src="demo/js/site.js"></script>
                <script>
                

                    var lightboxDescription = GLightbox({
                        selector: '.glightbox2',
                    });

                    lightboxDescription.on('close', () => {
                    // Do something
                    lightboxDescription.reload()
                });


                function choose_button(clicked_id){
                document.getElementById(clicked_id).innerHTML = "button text changed"

            }

            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plugin is creating separate elements for images and description which are dynamic so you cannot change that also currently there will be two buttons which has same id one which is created statically and another created by plugin that's why when you do `document.getElementById(clicked_id).innerHTML ..` the button which is static is getting change and you can see changes in slider when you re-open it .

Instead you can use **data-attributes** so whenever your button is clicked change the button which is static and which is created dynamically so that you can see changes without closing and re-opening your slider.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var lightboxDescription = GLightbox({
  selector: '.glightbox2',
});

lightboxDescription.on('close', () => {
  lightboxDescription.reload()
});

function choose_button(clicked_id) {
  //loop through same data-ids
  document.querySelectorAll('[data-id="' + clicked_id + '"]').forEach(function(el) {
    //change text
    el.textContent = "button text changed"
  })

}
```

```css
img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/glightbox/dist/css/glightbox.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/mcstudios/glightbox/dist/js/glightbox.min.js"></script>

<!-- Images with description example -->
<section class="section pair">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul class="box-container three-cols">
          <li class="box">
            <div class="inner">
              <a href="https://biati-digital.github.io/glightbox/demo/img/large/gm2.jpg" class="glightbox2" data-glightbox="title: Description Right; description: .custom-desc1; descPosition: left;">
                <img src="https://biati-digital.github.io/glightbox/demo/img/large/gm2.jpg" alt="image" />
              </a>

              <div class="glightbox-desc custom-desc1">
                <p>
                  <!--pass data-id-->
                  <button data-id="button1" onclick="choose_button(this.getAttribute('data-id'))">Wybierz1</button></p>

              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="box">
            <div class="inner">
              <a href="https://biati-digital.github.io/glightbox/demo/img/large/gm5.jpg" class="glightbox2" data-glightbox="title: Description Right; description: .custom-desc2; descPosition: left;">
                <img src="https://biati-digital.github.io/glightbox/demo/img/large/gm5.jpg" alt="image" />
              </a>

              <div class="glightbox-desc custom-desc2">
                <p>
                  <!--pass data-id-->
                  <button data-id="button2" onclick="choose_button(this.getAttribute('data-id'))">Wybierz2</button></p>

              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```